# JOIN inside a SELECT MAX in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query that returns these two elements.

```
SELECT ticket_holds.id, ticket_holds.created_at, orders.user_id, users.id, charges.payment_method 
  FROM ticket_holds 
LEFT JOIN order_items ON order_items.id = ticket_holds.order_item_id 
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.id = order_items.order_id 
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = orders.user_id 
LEFT JOIN charges on charges.order_id = orders.id;
```

This result is okay.

```
id |         created_at         | user_id | id | payment_method 
----+----------------------------+---------+----+----------------
  1 | 2017-05-26 04:29:22.189628 |       4 |  4 | 
  2 | 2017-05-26 04:33:00.721404 |       4 |  4 | some_payment_method
```

When I try to filter the query to display the last record created per user it also works okay using `SELECT MAX`.

```
SELECT ticket_holds.id, ticket_holds.created_at, orders.user_id, users.id, charges.payment_method 
  FROM ticket_holds 
LEFT JOIN order_items ON order_items.id = ticket_holds.order_item_id 
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.id = order_items.order_id 
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = orders.user_id
LEFT JOIN charges on charges.order_id = orders.id 
WHERE ticket_holds.created_at = (SELECT MAX(ticket_holds.created_at) FROM ticket_holds WHERE orders.user_id = users.id);
```

And the result

```
 id |         created_at         | user_id | id | payment_method 
----+----------------------------+---------+----+----------------
  2 | 2017-05-26 04:33:00.721404 |       4 |  4 | some_payment_method
(1 row)
```

However, when Im trying to filter to only select items without a `payment_method` I get no results.

```
SELECT ticket_holds.id, ticket_holds.created_at, orders.user_id, users.id, charges.payment_method 
  FROM ticket_holds
LEFT JOIN order_items ON order_items.id = ticket_holds.order_item_id 
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.id = order_items.order_id
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = orders.user_id 
LEFT JOIN charges on charges.order_id = orders.id 
WHERE ticket_holds.created_at = (SELECT MAX(ticket_holds.created_at) FROM ticket_holds WHERE orders.user_id = users.id AND charges.payment_method IS NULL);
```

(Notice the `AND charges.payment_method IS NULL)` and the end of the query)

This is what I get instead

```
 id | created_at | user_id | id | payment_method 
----+------------+---------+----+----------------
(0 rows)
```

Any idea how can I retrieve the elements with no payment method, in this case would be the record with id `1`?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: is payment_method null or simply empty "" ?

Comment: It would be null because if not present it would means the `charges` associated record does not exists.

Comment: I can't the see why, you could try http://sqlfiddle.com/ and we can play with it

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is still retrieving 0 either with NULL or "". It also returns 0 if I do `charges.payment_method != 'some_payment_method'`. It looks to me that for some reason it is skipping the result because it does not have a `change` associated record but have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: Your query with max returned 1 row with some payment method. After that you have added another filter charges.payment_method is null. Apart from that why you have added charges.payment_method is where clause sub query ?

Comment: good observation @FahadAnjum. If I move the `charges.payment_method IS NULL` outside the select and part of the where I still get the same 0 results.

Comment: Your subquery is also wrong. where orders.user_id = users.id i.e you are not fetching right max created date. Add table structure and sample data and output so that it will be easy for us to solve problem

Comment: @FahadAnjum could you provide an example?

Comment: ticket_holds.id what is purpose of this. why you have not used this id in your max subquery.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145267/discussion-between-fahad-anjum-and-martin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per discussion on chat. i think below query will help you to get required result.

```
with data as ( SELECT ticket_holds.id, ticket_holds.created_at, orders.user_id, users.id, charges.payment_method
FROM ticket_holds
LEFT JOIN order_items ON order_items.id = ticket_holds.order_item_id
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.id = order_items.order_id
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = orders.user_id
LEFT JOIN charges on charges.order_id = orders.id
where charges.payment_method is null

)
select * from data d1
where d1.created_at = (select max(created_at) from data d2
where d1.users_id = d2.user_id
)
```

There are few points while writing an sub query in where clause. Join your table carefully as in your case you are not utilizing any column for joining.